# google speech api -c# windows 10

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, windows-10

I have been trying to build a C# windows 10 application which transcribes a speech audio using google cloud speech api.

The code was working fine till 3 days back and since then I have started getting exceptions.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\SpeechRecognition\Trials\Hindi1\StandAlone\bin\Debug>standalone

Unhandled Exception: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unauthenticated, Detail="Exception occured in metadata credentials plugin.")
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.Calls.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2 call, TRequest req)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.Speech.SpeechClient.Recognize(RecognizeRequest request, CallOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<Create>b__1(TRequest req, CallSettings cs)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.Sync(TRequest request, CallSettings perCallCallSettings)
   at Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.SpeechClientImpl.Recognize(RecognizeRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.SpeechClient.Recognize(RecognitionConfig config, RecognitionAudio audio, CallSettings callSettings)
   at StandAlone.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\SpeechRecognition\Trials\Hindi1\StandAlone\Program.cs:line 288
```

This is happening only on windows 10. Same StandAlone is working o.k on windows 7.

I have tried to use dependency walker for c# but it does not work.
problem seems to be with some update on os.

I would appreciate help on
1. How to track dependency changes
2. How to Authenticate to SpeechClient

Comment: It was working fine and exceptions started without you changing anything?

Comment: Please pre-format your stack trace (use 4 spaces indentation) so it'll be easier to review. Thx!

Comment: I am not clear what is pre-format (for HTML ?) . The stack trace looks decent enough. I think I could clarify a specific item/line.

Comment: For Dani  --That's right Exceptions started without me changing source code/project. There are always updates on the OS/Runtime. The windows 7 where it still runs probably  has an earlier runtime. That is the reason I am trying to figure out dependencies